# Failure to Empty Trash

Tags: macos, external-disk

I have an iMac20 with OS 10.6.8 and an external hard drive. It appears that recently the Trash has an large amount of items. When I try to use Secure Empty Trash it counts the number of items to be deleted, then starts the deletion process and fails after a short time.

Comment: If you disconnect the external - does trash empty then?

Comment: Yes, it appears that the problem is with the external hard drive

Answer (score 4):

You could try using terminal.
I suppose that you can not remove the files from external drive trash (Mac use separated trashed for each drive).

In order to remove external drive files try this:

1. Open Terminal
2. Write: `cd /Volumes/{Your External Drive Name}/.Trash`
3. Check that your files are there with: `ls -la`
4. Remove them using: `sudo rm -rf ./*`
5. It will ask your password

With that you should be able to remove your files.
You can do the same for your local drive but the `.Trash` folder is on your user folder instead of the drive root.

Comment: Having established that the Trash was on the External Hard Drive I connected such to another newer Mac and was able to empty the Trash from there.